# How to enable assertions in AWS Lambda Java code?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, assertion

How to enable assertions in AWS Lambda Java code ?

Basically I want AWS Lambda to take into account my assert statements in Java code.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Bjorn you have too enable `-enableassertions`.

It is possible to have them but with using custom runtime not the default AWS.
Here is one example of having custom runtime - https://github.com/andthearchitect/aws-lambda-java-runtime

Note: There is an option JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, please give it a try before checking custom runtime.

Another option could be just replace asserting with something like .

```java
if (!condition) {
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

If it is your own code second options sounds better.

Comment: Exactly! Wanted to know if I could avoid writing conditions by enabling assertions. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Thanks! I did not know this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

To enable assertions assertions you need to use the `-enableassertions` startup command. Unfortunately you cannot give arguments to the JVM with AWS Lambda. Only environment variables are supported. To answer your question: no this is not possible.